# Check box with submit button not working

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a page where if the checkbox is checked then it should echo "g". I know that the echoing "g" works because I tired it with only pressing the button.

```
<? require("Left.php"); ?>
<? include_once("connect.php"); ?>
<form method="post" >
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
<?php
if($ownstarter = true){
echo 'User starter';
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' id='checkbox'>";
}
?>
</form>
<?
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if ($_POST['test'] == 'checkbox') {
        echo 'g';
}
}
?>
<? require("Right.php"); ?>
```

Comment: Is this the whole code for this site? If yes, $gold is set to 0+5 and $id isn't set at all, neither is $_POST['test']

Comment: It's really hard to say what you're trying to achieve. Firstly, you don't have a form element named `test`, and secondly, it would only be true if the value of the checkbox was `checkbox`, one that isn't set. Also, I'm not sure what you're wanting to do with `if($ownstarter = true){` that conditional statement may not be valid, and may need a `==` instead of `=` - `if($ownstarter == true){` and knowing how `$ownstarter` is being set. You will need to further elaborate on your question in order to give you a concrete answer. As it stands, your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are testing for the 'test' variable in POST, but ure sending the 'checkbox'
if you want to send a variable for 'checkbox' set attribute 'value=""' in the checkbox.
Then you can do this:

```
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     if ($_POST['checkbox'] == 'yourValue') {
         $gold = $gold +5;
    }
}
```

otherwise do this:

```
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     if (isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
         $gold = $gold +5;
    }
}
```

Comment: $_POST['VARNAME'] -> <input name="VARNAME">